# Combo boxes in a continuous form

Tags: ms-access

I have my combo boxes setup with a value list as the row source and a value in a table set as the control source. Even with this setup, I can only change the value of the combo boxes on the last/bottom-most record. If I try to change the records of any other combo boxes nothing happens. I have been searching for a solution and have only found the suggestion to use a control source, which my combo boxes are already doing. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

A combobox on a continuous form must be bound to a field in the table  or query on which the form is based to work properly, otherwise it will only show data relevant to the current record.

However, in this case, it looks like your form is set to disallow edit. Ensure that Allow Edits on the property tab is set to Yes.

Comment: It is bound to a field in a table, but I can still only change the bottom-most combo boxes

Comment: Have you checked that you are allowed to edit? Can you update textboxes on other rows?

Comment: Okay, please post the details of the combobox, that is row source, row source type, bound column, control source.

Comment: Control Source- TransactionType  
Row Source- "Purchase";"Return"  
Row Source Type- Value List  
Bound Column- 1  
  
I think I have fixed the problem though, I ditched my original form and just created a new one from scratch. There must have been a some setting in the old form preventing this. Got it working now though, thanks for your help.